# React-Native Geolocation API on Background (android)

Tags: java, android, react-native, geolocation

I'm currently working on a project that needs a background geolocation mode to send the user current position.
I'm using the module [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) But i'm having problems because the app crashes after 15 -20 minutes with this error :

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask

Is there any solution to this error?

Also, I want to try the React Native Geolocation API: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

But does this API work in Background on **Android**? the docs mention it needs extra configuration on iOS but doesnt mention anything about android

Comment: Show use the code and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I have also used https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service and it is perfectly working when app is open, could you please help me to make it work in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

After some test i found that my configuration was bad. I was testing the example, which include a `url` option, which i didn't need.

And second I was calling `BackgroundGeolocation.start()` before my listeners where mounted. After changing this all works as expected.

Comment: I have also used https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service and it is perfectly working when app is open, could you please help me to make it work in background

Comment: @rulogaf can you please share your configurations?